# How to group ManyToMany in template

Tags: django, django-templates

Here is my model:

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)  
    subjects = models.ManyToManyField(Subject)

class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    type = models.ForeignKey(SubjectType)   

class SubjectType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I want to do something like that in template:

```
{regroup subjects by subject.type}
  {foreach subject_type}
    #display all teachers for subject_type
```

Each subject has its `teacher_set`.
How can i union all teachers for a particular subject_type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can't get this functionality from the template. However, you could do it in your view:

```
subject_type = # Some SubjectType object
my_teachers = []
for subject in subject_type.subject_set:
    my_teachers += subject.teacher_set
# What we do with the duplicates?
my_teachers = list(set(my_teachers))
```

Now, you have a list of unique teachers in `my_teachers` for a particular SubjectType.

**EDIT:** You could do this for every SubjectType object and pass the resulting list (of lists) to the template.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I understand that before starting to mess around with django I should learn python. :)

Comment: @VladimirNani, I wouldn't say _before_, I would say _simultaneously_